# How to Monitoring/Profile Web project running on Glassfish

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiling

Is it possible to monitor/profile a web project that is running on Glassfish server?

What I want to achieve is to `1` - find out memory usage, `2` - slow running code of my web application(Is it possible to only monitor a single war file or get some statistics related to a war file?)

I tried `jconsole` and `jvisualvm` but my application does not appear (or at least it does not appear by name, Maybe Glassfish instance need to be monitored).

Honestly speaking, I am not sure how exactly one can monitor a war, jar or ear project.

I also don't know what terms to search to be able to tell "My application is using this much memory, this much is memory leak and these part of the codes are running slow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A profiler always profiles the entire JVM, not just one WAR separately. Probably you have specific packages for the code in your WAR file, you you can set the call tree filters in such a way that only those classes are measured. To see the memory consumption related to a WAR file you would have to find the class loader of the web application and look at its retained objects.

> but my application does not appear

Sometimes it's not straight-forward to identify the JVM that runs the web application. The Glassfish start script starts another JVM and that is the one you're interested in.

Some profilers have integration wizards that make it easier to get the correct JVM, for example [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has an integration wizard for Glassfish.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.